# How to get react-quill to output with light and dark mode capabilities

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, wysiwyg, darkmode, react-quill

I am using react-quill (WYSIWYG editor) for a Material Ui project. I am wondering how to change the style output of the editor to work with the light and dark mode toggle of Material Ui?

Currently, react-quill outputs: `<p><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">In consideration of the risk of injury...` for just typing in regular text. As you can see it explicitly gives an RGB value for Black, which overrides the light/dark mode toggle of Material Ui. Do you know of any options for either changing the output for those specific styles or removing the styles when typing in default color text?